# How to check Oracle database In-Memory space?

Tags: in-memory-database, oracle12c

I wanted to check the allocated in-memory size of my oracle database. I tried with the query below, but it is not working

```
SELECT pool,alloc_bytes,used_bytes,populate_status FROM V$INMEMOTY_AREA;
```

Error-
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a typo in the view name. Instead of the word `memory` you mistyped `memoty`.

And here's a proof:

**Your query**

```
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT pool,alloc_bytes,used_bytes,populate_status FROM V$INMEMOTY_AREA;
SELECT pool,alloc_bytes,used_bytes,populate_status FROM V$INMEMOTY_AREA
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

SQL>
```

**My query**

```
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT pool,alloc_bytes,used_bytes,populate_status FROM V$INMEMORY_AREA;

POOL                                                                           ALLOC_BYTES USED_BYTES POPULATE_STATUS
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1MB POOL                                                                                 0          0 OUT OF MEMORY
64KB POOL                                                                                0          0 OUT OF MEMORY

SQL>
```

**Enjoy!**

Comment: your answer does not give any value to me. you have typed the same query again instead of giving a correct one.

Comment: @Dinidu, are you sure? :-) You have "v$inmemo**T**y_area" in your query, whereas I have "v$inmemo**R**y_area" in my query. (Please note the bold uppercase letters in this comment.) Read my answer once again and more thoroughly.